# You tube Code for Loading search results for a specified query

Tags: youtube-api

I need the code to show videos from youtube for a specified query.

I would like to show all videos on youtube on my website for "car washing" so my visitors don't need to leave my site and can watch them and look through a list of "car washing" Videos.

I have tried over the past week to create the code with youtube api but its just not working and i think i have it wrong somewhere, so if any of you can create the code to show "car washing" videos then i will be able to see where i went wrong.

Can you help?

Comment: Could you post the code that failed? Maybe we can help you to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what you've tried, or what problems you've encountered. I suggest starting with the online Youtube gdata API demo: http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

Here you can "safely" play with parameters for your API requests. Entering "car washing" in the Search Query field in the demo menitioned above yields the query URL

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=car washing , which gives you the data you need - XML as default.

Comment: Just checked and basically I’ve been doing the wrong thing all this time and back at the start again and can’t work out where to start – looks like I can’t do it because I don’t have the brain power to work it out. I’ve tried to find people for hire that could do it for me but still can’t find anybody.

1st of all – can it be done with the right knowledge?

Comment: What I want is a YouTube video player at the top and the Search results “car washing” below which is my specified query. My visitors can click on the car washing videos below and watch them on the YouTube player at the top. Ideally the specified query results part would show the video icon and the video title and when they click either it would start playing on the YouTube player.
2nd of all – if it can be done do you know the full code or do any of you know where I can hire somebody or company to create the code.

Comment: I know this might sound silly if it can be done easily but I can’t do it so I need to hire or do without. It’s just getting put on a webpage so I think it would need to be an iframe code.

If I had the full ready to copy and paste code then I could see the set out and everything would click in place in my head, tried to Google it but that brought me to here and YouTube api center.

Thanks

Comment: It can be done. But asking for a complete solution is perhaps a bit over the top. I doubt nobody is having the complete solution in their snippet box.

Comment: ... especially since you have not yet even told us what programming language/environment you are working with. If you are not up to being guided through the process and do the work yourself, there's always places like https://www.odesk.com